# How to return response from sql query in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a simple translator API which takes English word as parameter from user and returns Italian counterpart from MySQL database. Here is my VB.NET Controller

```
Public Function GetValue(EnglishWord As String)
        Dim connStr As String = "server=mysql.mydatabase.com;user=myuser;database=mydatabase;port=3306;password=mypassword;"
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        conn.Open()
        Dim command = New MySqlCommand("SELECT ItalianWord FROM Book WHERE EnglishWord=(" + EnglishWord + ")", conn)
        Dim reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Return reader.GetValue(0)
        Console.WriteLine("Done.")

    End Function
```

Return value however is quite strange:

[image]

I expect only one string value and that is not `value1` or `value2`. What I'm doing wrong? Any advise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Using...End Using` to be sure that your database objects are disposed.

Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execute...`

Functions in vb.net require a `DataType`.

`Console.WriteLine` will never execute because you have left the function on the previous line with `Return`

Always use parameters to avoid Sql injection. I had to guess at the datatype of `EnglishWord`. Check your database for correct type.

I am assuming that there is only a single translated word for each English word.

```
Public Function GetValue(EnglishWord As String) As String
    Dim connStr As String = "server=mysql.mydatabase.com;user=myuser;database=mydatabase;port=3306;password=mypassword;"
    Dim TranslatedWord As Object
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr),
            command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT ItalianWord FROM Book WHERE EnglishWord=@EnglishWord;", conn)
        command.Parameters.Add("@EnglishWord", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EnglishWord
        con.Open()
        TranslatedWord = command.ExecuteScalar
    End Using
    If TranslatedWord Is Nothing Then
        Return "No word found."
    Else
        Return TranslatedWord.ToString
    End If
End Function
```